# Prime problems java

Tags: java

A prime number is a positive integer greater than 1 that is divisible only by itself and 1. In this assignment you are responsible to write a complete Java program to display first N prime numbers. In other words, your program should list the first N prime numbers.

Functional Requirements

Your program should prompt the user for a positive number, or a value of -1 to terminate the program. If the user enters 0, or a negative number, the program will also end immediately.
Your program will display the first N prime numbers given by the user. For example, if the user enters 3, the program should display: “2, 3, 5” which are the first three prime numbers. If the user enters 6, the output would be: “2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13”.

Sample Run

```
Welcome to the list of N prime numbers program!
===============================================
Please enter the value of N (positive integer):
6

First 6 prime numbers are:
2
3
5
7
11
13
```

When i worked on it i got this but need help finishing

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Welcome to the list of N prime numbers program! \n========================================================\nPlease enter the value of N (positive integer): ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        int status=1;
        int num=3;
        n = scan.nextInt();
        if(n>=1) {
            System.out.println(2);
            for(int count=2; count<=n; count++) {
                for(int j=2; j<=Math.sqrt(num);j++) {
                    if(num%j==0) {
                        status =0;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(status!=0) {
                        System.out.println(num);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                status=1;
                num++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your program is doing differently than what you expect.

Comment: Your `if(status!=0)` should be outside the for loop. Other than that - yes, we would have appreciated better description of what the issue was. :)

Comment: Little tips. `j*j <= num` would be much faster than `j<=Math.sqrt(num)`

Comment: @RickyMo Even faster if you precalculate `Math.sqrt(num)` and then just have `j<sqrt_num` in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

please use below method to get prime no.

```
static List<Integer> nthPrimeNo(int nth){
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

    int num, count, i;
    num=2;
    count=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < nth; j++) {
        while (count < j){
            num=num+1;
            for (i = 2; i <= num; i++){
                if (num % i == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( i == num){
                count = count+1;
            }
        }
        integers.add(num);
    }
    return integers;
}
```

Or do you want to get 10 greater than primes number,

```
static List<Integer> sieveOfEratosthenes(int n) {
    boolean prime[] = new boolean[n + 1];
    Arrays.fill(prime, true);
    for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++) {
        if (prime[p]) {
            for (int i = p * 2; i <= n; i += p) {
                prime[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    List<Integer> primeNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (prime[i]) {
            primeNumbers.add(i);
        }
    }
    return primeNumbers;
}
```

Comment: This does not give the first n primes, it gives the primes <= n.

Comment: The `nthPrimeNo` method generates the smaller primes over and over again. This is very wasteful and slow.

Answer (score 0):

you should give a `out.println("enter the number of prime numbers needed");`
then read it using scanner(for example if it is reading into x) and provide a if condition as

```
if(x<=0)
{
break;
}
```

and balance code can be given in the else condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class prime {

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for(int j=2; j<=Math.sqrt(n)+1;j++) { //Math.sqrt(n) + 1 because you want to check more than half of the original value.
        if(n%j==0) {
            return false;
        }
    }       
    return true;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Welcome to the list of N prime numbers program! \n========================================================\nPlease enter the value of N (positive integer): ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputNum; //try making the variable name meaningful
    inputNum = scan.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    int startingVal = 2;

    while(count<inputNum) {
        if(inputNum==-1) {
            break;
        }
        if(count==0) {
            System.out.println(2);
            count++;
        }
        else if(isPrime(startingVal)) {
            System.out.println(startingVal);
            count++;
        }
        startingVal ++;

    }
}
```

}

This should work fine. As @Amadan in the comment section already mentioned, your program did not work because your if(status!=0) is in the for loop.

Also, setting the variable names meaningful helps you fix or edit your code easier.

Answer (score -2):

use this function call `System.exit(0);` in exit condition